# Why is the div outside of the maximum width of the background when I resize the canvas

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning css and html and I have tried and tried for many days to fix the solution but it end up worse and now I asked help here, can anyone help me why is ".hometext1" is outside of the max width of the background img? I am gonna leave the codes here1

```css
    body,html {
        font-family: Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0; 
        background-color: #ffffff;
        line-height: 1.0;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
   
    /*parallax*/  
    .bg1 {
        background-image: url('./assets/background/bg3.jpg');
        min-height: 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        opacity: .75;
    }
    .bg2 {
        background-image: url('./assets/background/bg2.jpg');
        min-height: 50%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        opacity: .75;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1600px) {
        .bg1, .bg2 {
          background-attachment: scroll;
          min-height: 400px;
          min-width: none;
        }
    }
    .hometext1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .hometext2 {
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        padding: 50px 50px;
        font-size: 30px;
        animation: opac 2s;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    @keyframes opac{
        0%{
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100%
        {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    .content {
        height: 50%;
        text-align: center;

    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="author" content="ozakiharumi">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>
                TEST
            </title>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/favicon/favico2.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--parallax background 1-->
            <div class="bg1">
                <div class="hometext1">
                <span class="hometext2">ARE YOU READY FOR QUANTUM MECHANICS?</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--main content-->
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Quantum Overdose!</h2>
            </div>
            <!--parallax background 2-->
            <div class="bg2"></div>
            <!--footer-->
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="footer-text">© 2021 Quantum Overdose!. All Rights Reserved.</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**PLS HELP ME**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to avoid this problem is to write the `.hometext1` class style as you see fit in the blocks below. The test application is available at [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/sercansebetci/rw0jh79d/3/). You are having problems because the `@media` block you added continues to be applied when the page is minimized. Delete the `@media` block you added and apply the styles you expect when the page gets smaller, using the following structure.

```css
/* Desktop:  1024px > Browser Screen Width > Infinity */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .hometext1{
    /* Styles */
    }
}

/* Tablet: 768px > Browser Screen Width > 1023px */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .hometext1{
    /* Styles */
    }
}

/* Smarthphone: 0px > Browser Screen Width > 768px */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .hometext1{
    /* Styles */
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this, I also put the .hometext2 inside of each @media and everything went good. +rep

Comment: You are welcome, you can vote well for it to be seen by the community.